# Prove that $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^k})=\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}x^j$

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

How I can demonstrate the following equation?

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^k})=\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}x^j$$

It is easy to apply the geometric sum: 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}x^j=\frac{1-x^{2^n}}{1-x}$$

How can I find the formula for this equation?: $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^k}) =\text{???}$$

Comment: This is a statement about representing numbers in binary in disguise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1-x^{2^{k+1}}}{1-x^{2^{k}}}=\frac{1}{1-x}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-x^{2^{k+1}}\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(1-x^{2^{k+1}}\right)^{-1}=\color{red}{\frac{1-x^{2^{n}}}{1-x}}.$$

Comment: Could you tell me how to get that equality?: $\frac{1-x^{2^{k+1}}}{1-x^{2^{k}}}=1+x^{2^{k}}$

Comment: @DarioGutierrez It follows from $$(1-x^{2})=(1+x)(1-x).$$ If you don't see why tell me, I will add more details.

Comment: Yes please, or a link. Thank you!

Comment: @DarioGutierrez Take $x^{2^{k}}$ instead of $x$ in the identity I wrote in the comment. You get $$(1-(x^{2^{k}})^{2})=(1+x^{2^{k}})(1-x^{2^{k}})$$ but $$(x^{2^{k}})^{2}=x^{2^{k+1}}.$$ I hope is more clear now. If you want to prove the identity in the other comment, just do the multiplication in the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Use 
\begin{align}
\frac{1-x^{2^{j+1}}}{1-x^{2^{j}}}=1+x^{2^{j}}.
\end{align}

Comment: Could you tell me how to get that equality?

Comment: @DarioGutierrez By $(1-y^{2})/(1-y)=1+y, y=x^{2^{j}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion as already suggested gives the easiest proof. But you may also carry out the (huge) product and note that you get $2^n$ terms of the form
$$ x^{b_0+2b_1 +4b_2 + \cdots + 2^{n-1} b_{n-1}}$$
where the $b_k$'a are either zero or one (depending on choosing the factor $1$ or $x^{2^k}$. Ans the exponent is precisely the binary expansion of all integers from $0$ to $2^{n}-1$.